# StaticFiles vs MediaFiles

Tags: django, static, media

What is the difference between static files and media files? Django says that the SATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT must be different. I just know that in static folder we can have css files and images or other files to be uploaded goes to media folder. I have directory as

static

```
|-->images

|-->css
```

in settings.py >>

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

---

Is the ROOT and URL for static and media files are okay or not?

Answer (score 0):

- *MEDIA_ROOT* is the folder where files uploaded using FileField will go.
- *STATIC_ROOT* is the folder where static files will be stored after
  using manage.py collectstatic
- We generally use *STATIC_ROOT* in production